# ASP.Net MVC 4 – Resource Cannot be found error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax

My project was working fine till yesterday and today I renamed the namespace from **OnlineShoppingSystemMVC** to **OnlineShoppingSystemMvc**

And then I changed the markup of Global.asax I changed

```
<%@ Application 
Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
Inherits="OnlineShoppingSystemMvc.MvcApplication" 
Language="C#" %>
```

But still resource cannot found error is thrown when I debug the application.

Please help me out in solving this issue.

Comment: I changed it using ctrl+r, r and changed the name space

Comment: clean and rebuild solution and make sure namespace is renamed all the places

Comment: I did what you have suggested but still no luck

Comment: the issue is i am sure this that at some place old namespace name used.

Comment: Ok I will check it once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename all

`@model OnlineShoppingSystemMVC.YourModelsFolder.YourModel`

to

`@model OnlineShoppingSystemMvc.YourModelsFolder.YourModel` in all your View files

Right now I did what you did before (I renamed the namespace of one of my projects (ctrl+ R)) and all the namespaces was renamed but the models' namespaces in my Views didn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
I find solution for your issue:

My project name is WebApplication1 after this rename it to WebApplication3 .

I was  change  this line in aspx page:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" **Inherits="WebApplication3.test"** %>
I done changes also in AssemblyInfo.cs :
**[assembly: AssemblyTitle("WebApplication3")]**
and **[assembly: AssemblyProduct("WebApplication3")]**

and also change in test.aspx.cs:

**namespace WebApplication3**

after this running project it works absolutely fine.
Hope it will help you
```